# submit fails to post

Tags: php, mysql

If the `sub1` has been submitted to show the submit button of `sub2` and show its value, it will give a notice of:

> Notice: Undefined index: sub1

though the submit button is already there and it does not give the value of `sub1`

What is the reason?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<form method="post">
<input type='submit' name='sub1' value='sub1'>
<?php
if(array_key_exists('sub1',$_POST))
{
echo"<input type='submit' name='sub2' value='sub2'>";
}
if(array_key_exists('sub2',$_POST))
{
echo $_POST['sub1'];
}
?>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: completly unreadable and hard to edit wall of code

Comment: what you mean? do you want to see the whole of it?in pastebin?

Comment: it's possibly to post result of var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: $_POST comes from a form... if it's not in the form (hidden field, text field or whatever...), be sure it won't be anywhere in the $_POST.  Check your form fields.  print_r($_POST);

Comment: yes it has result in ifarray_key_exists('myid',..) and here is the output: string(1) "1"

Comment: View the source of your page before you submit. What does the submit button look like? Is the value populated? Maybe it's submitting a blank value.

Comment: Sorry, you've exhausted my ideas.

Comment: does it have any problem to echo"<input type='submit' name='insert' value='insert this drug'/>"; that i put it in the 
if(array_key_exists('myid',$_POST))?maybe the problem is here

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As newz leads to, change the field that you are expecting to have the myid value to type 'hidden'.  Then it should pass the value correctly.  You will have to add a submit button, and set the name to something else besides 'myid'.

Comment: would you please tell me exactly what do you mean? i didn't understand

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about expecting the value of a submit button. If the user presses enter on a text field then it may submit without that value. It's hard to make sense of your question though. Here's a debugging trick I use. In your code that runs on post, try inserting the command

```
phpinfo(32);
```

This will cause your page to show a table of the diagnostic information for your form submission.

Comment: Yes, anywhere, but before you redirect if you do so. My code often has an if($_POST) block. I'd put it in there.

Comment: $_POST['myid'] doesn't exist in this table but why?:((